# In Javascript, How can I replace the name of element with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

How can I replace the name of element "The_Iframe_Element_Name" with the variable "elemName" in the following:

```
  function fnFrame(elemName) {
      setTimeout(function () {
          var iframeBody = window.The_Iframe_Element_Name.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
              $(iframeBody).addClass("xyz");
      }, 500);
  }
```

Comment: You can use `window["any_name"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```
var iframeName = 'foo';
var iframeBody = window[iframeName].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

Note that you will only be able to access the content of an iframe if it's within the same URL schema as the parent window.

Comment: oh, that easy :D .. Thanks

Comment: yeh, it's only a fancyBox iFrame where I need to adjust classes according to the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
function fnFrame(elemName) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var iframeBody = window[elemName].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            $(iframeBody).addClass("xyz");
    }, 500);
}

fnFrame('The_Iframe_Element_Name');
```